# efficient way to store cdn image path in database

Tags: image-uploading, cdn

we would like to store uploaded images on cdn server in our website. We are thinking to add fallback in our system if cdn service goes down. so images are start to upload on server hard disk in this case. we can manage this fallback using general setting option.

what is efficient way to store upload images path in our database ? we have to store full image url or image name in database. so we can recover easily in fallback situation.

Comment: Although I'm not sure why you want to know the exact physical location on the CDN .... then using relative paths from a (per location) configurable would be a way to make sure the files are handled in a uniform way in the data storage.-

Comment: i think you are not getting my question. just want to know that have to store full image url path along with cdn url in database or just image name ? so we can easily migrate image uploading in fallback case.